# What is the mechanism by which $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^\frac{\ln{x}}{x}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}$ is allowed?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've encountered a number of problems in my coursework that require me to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{\frac{1}{x}}$, the solutions to which apply the following identity:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^\frac{\ln{x}}{x}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}$$

What principle allows us to move the limit operator into the exponent?  Are there any conditions (aside from the limit not existing) under which this is not allowed?